# Infinite call for animation time not working for "all" elements

Tags: jquery, css, animation, recursion, infinite

I am trying to run the following animation for a set of `div` elements (lets say 50), however, the `$.each()` function is only working for the first element in the array.

```
$.each(droplets, function(){
splashVanish(this);
 }); 



  function splashVanish(droplet) {
   droplet.fadeOut(500, function(){
     droplet.css({'top':Math.random()*600+'px','left':Math.random()*1400+'px'});
     droplet.remove();
     $("body").append(droplet);
             //recursive call for infinite animation time
     droplet.fadeIn(500,function(){splashVanish(droplet)}); 
   });
 }
```

When the above code runs, only the first `div` in the array fadesOut, randomizes position and fadesIn for infinite animatiion duration. Sadly, all the other 49 `div`s are static and not executing the same function.

Comment: What is a _dropplet_? Is it a jQuery object? What is _droplets_? A collection of jQ objects? An array of some sort?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't make that clear..Its just a `div` element

Comment: It strongly feels like `this` is the whole collection in `$.each` callback, while jquery doc states it should be a current value for each call. Have you tried to breakpoint there and inspect `this` value?

Comment: Oh I see, so you mean, `this` as opposed to `$(this)` points to the collection itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, if `droplets` is a collection of `div`s you need to use `each()` instead. `$.each()` iterates arrays. Try this and see if it works.

```
droplets.each(function(){
    splashVanish($(this));
});
```